# How to fix the error code on android 'MainActivity' not declared

Tags: android, android-activity, error-handling, compiler-errors

Error running 'app': The activity 'MainActivity' is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml

I've been getting this error code about 12 hours ago and trying to fix the problem. It seems to be related to package or activity on the codes: so here's what I've come up with

```
<activity android:name="com.dot.forklift.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Sync grandle and invalidated caches didn't work out for this matter; also, clean project didn't do much for this.

Even after those, the program is neither able to detect the activity nor to run properly. Keep sending the exact same error code as above.
I don't know where to research anymore and hard stuck on this same problem, please help me out.

Comment: You're positive `com.dot.forklift.MainActivity` is correct? What if you just do `.MainActivity`

Comment: Edit your question. Post your entire manifest.